# Kendo UI Grid ASP.net MVC Adding sum totals at bottom for multiple

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to get the sum value of multiple fields, I know how to do one but not sure how to do multiple. What I have is this :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Result)
                                            .Name("grid1")
                                            .Columns(col =>
                                            {
                                                col.Bound("Date").Format("{0:n2}").Format("{0:d}");
                                                col.Bound("ClientAge").Format("{0:n2}");
                                                col.Bound("PartnerAge").Format("{0:n2}");
                                                col.Bound("TotalGrossIncome").Format("{0:n2}");
                                                col.Bound("TotalExpenditure").Format("{0:n2}");
                                                col.Bound("TotalNetIncome").Format("{0:n2}");
                                                col.Bound("TotalAssets").Format("{0:n2}");
                                                col.Bound("TotalLiabilities").Format("{0:n2}");
                                                col.Bound("TotalNetAssetValue").Format("{0:n2}");
                                            }
                                            ) 
                                            .Scrollable()
                                            .Selectable(select => select.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
                                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                                .Server()                                               
                                                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Date))
                                            ).Deferred(true)
                                        )
```

I basically need the sum value in the footer for following

```
                                                col.Bound("TotalGrossIncome").Format("{0:n2}");
                                                col.Bound("TotalExpenditure").Format("{0:n2}");
                                                col.Bound("TotalNetIncome").Format("{0:n2}");
                                                col.Bound("TotalAssets").Format("{0:n2}");
                                                col.Bound("TotalLiabilities").Format("{0:n2}");
                                                col.Bound("TotalNetAssetValue").Format("{0:n2}")
```

Can anyone assist me with this please not a kendo guru yet :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I managed to get it sorted :D Have a look below. According to Kendo's Documentation the Template is actually incorrect - using #=sum# is referring to client side as to the initial example for ASP.net. I approached this with a different method and working find now.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Result)
    .Name("grid1")
    .Columns(col =>
    {
        col.Bound("Date").Format("{0:n2}").Format("{0:d}").FooterTemplate("TOTALS");
        col.Bound("ClientAge").Format("{0:n2}");
        col.Bound("PartnerAge").Format("{0:n2}");
        col.Bound(p => p.TotalGrossIncome).Format("{0:n2}").FooterTemplate(@<text>@item.Sum.Format("{0:c}")</text>);
        col.Bound(p => p.TotalExpenditure).Format("{0:n2}").FooterTemplate(@<text>@item.Sum.Format("{0:c}")</text>);
        col.Bound(p => p.TotalNetIncome).Format("{0:n2}").FooterTemplate(@<text>@item.Sum.Format("{0:c}")</text>);
        col.Bound(p => p.TotalAssets).Format("{0:n2}").FooterTemplate(@<text>@item.Sum.Format("{0:c}")</text>);
        col.Bound(p => p.TotalLiabilities).Format("{0:n2}").FooterTemplate(@<text>@item.Sum.Format("{0:c}")</text>);
        col.Bound(p => p.TotalNetAssetValue).Format("{0:c}").FooterTemplate(@<text>@item.Sum.Format("{0:c}")</text>);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Selectable(select => select.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Server()
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Date))
        .PageSize(100)
        .Aggregates(aggregates =>
        {
            aggregates.Add(p => p.TotalGrossIncome).Sum();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.TotalExpenditure).Sum();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.TotalNetIncome).Sum();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.TotalAssets).Sum();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.TotalLiabilities).Sum();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.TotalNetAssetValue).Sum();                                                      
        })
    )
    .Deferred(true)
)
```

Comment: The example on Kendo's website is here - clearly using client-side mixed with server-side and functioning not as the example indicates. http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/aggregates